# How to pass a variables to a project that is Library?

Tags: android, variables

Is there a way to pass a variable (ex. String) from a Main Activity to another Project that was set as a Library?

Comment: As a parameter to a method? The harder part is passing from the library to the main project (which isn't possible).

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to pass data back and forth between Activities and Services in the same way as you would between Activities and Services that are in your main project.

The "library" flag pretty much only tells the system not to create a .apk at compile time.